# Render Paperclip Avatar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, devise, paperclip, avatar

I'm trying to render a User's Avatar on a Show Page.

Scenario:
User creates Account and set's Avatar.
Avatar is displayed correctly oh his Profile page(stretchy but its there).
But on another Page is says

```
undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass
```

the code is

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:avatar), class: "size48" %>
```

**Edit**

In my Views folder the image get's rendered only on the USERS folder, on the other folders im getting this error.

UserModel -> http://pastebin.com/pdTTLgrw

Comment: Can you show your `User` model?

Comment: User Model -> http://pastebin.com/pdTTLgrw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@user` variable is `nil`. There should be `@user = User.find(params[:id])` in the controller action of the page you're trying to load.

Comment: I'm trying to load it at the pin/show Layout. Do i just add in the Pins Controller @user = User.find(params[:id]) , because im getting the error. User with id=17 not found.

Comment: Thanks, found it. Added it in the Pins Controller and it worked with current_user!